# Attach child entities via id-array to parent entity in a generic way

Tags: c#, generics, entity-framework-core

While using a generic repository pattern, I have the following function for adding an entity:

```
public class BaseRepository<TEntity> : IBaseRepository<TEntity>
    where TEntity : class, IEntity
{
    public async Task<TEntity> AddEntity(TEntity entity)
    {
        this.databaseContext.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);
        await this.databaseContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        return entity;
    }
}
```

I have two entities, having a one-to-many relationship between company and user:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Company
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

I receive a User Model from my Controller with the following properties:

```
{
    string Name = "Example User",
    int[] Companies = [1, 3, 7] <--- representing existing company-id's
}
```

Could I now somehow go from `int[] Companies` to a populated `List<Company> Companies` *in a generic way* (since I have multiple entities like this)?

Perhaps something like:

- Get all 'Navigation Property Names' from 'TEntity', which would result in 'Companies'.
- Then, find the matching properties within the controller model, which would result in `int[] Companies`.
- Then, populate `List<Company> Companies` based on the id's within the matched `int[] Companies`.
- Finally, save TEntity.

Could something like this be achieved?

Answer (score -1):

You need to do it in Service/Unit of work/whatever 2nd layer you use before calling generic methods from BaseRepository.

If user is new,

YourService.cs or YourUnitOfWork.cs

```
public void Save(User user, int[] companiesID)
{
    var companies = YourBaseRepositoryCompany.GetEntities(x => companiesID.contains(x.Id));
    user.Companies = companies;
    YourBaseRepositoryUser.SaveEntities(user);
}
```

If your user is existing, you just can call BaseRepositoryUser's save in controller. all entities will be updated.